# Officejs word add-ins, method saveAsync not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, office-js

Just starting with OfficeJs. I came across a very strange problem, there are some cases in which the Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync is not saving but it doesn't throw any error. Why could this be happening? I didn't find a pattern to reproduce it, it just happens sometimes and if I do a reload it fixes it. Im using Angular 7 whith Officejs.

Word Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20324) 64-bit.

This is how I am saving:

```
protected saveSetting<T>(key, val): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(subscriber => { 
    try {                 
      Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync((asyncResult) => { 
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) { 
          console.log('saveAsync failed: ' + asyncResult.error.message);              
        } 
        Office.context.document.settings.set(key, val); 
        Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync((result) => { 
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) { 
            console.log('saveAsync failed: ' + result.error.message);                  
          } 
          subscriber.next(val); 
          subscriber.complete();              
        });          
      });       
    } catch (e) { 
      subscriber.error('Error saving setting ' + key); 
      subscriber.complete();       
    } 
  }); 
}
```

And this is how I'm getting the value:

```
protected getSetting<T>(key): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(subscriber => { 
    try { 
      Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync((asyncResult) => { 
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) { 
          console.log('saveAsync failed: ' + asyncResult.error.message);             
        }  
        subscriber.next(Office.context.document.settings.get(key)); 
        return subscriber.complete();          
      });      
    } catch (e) { 
      subscriber.next(null); 
      return subscriber.complete();      
    }   
  }); 
}
```

Thanks!

I try debugging and it never returns an error, it always seems to save but it does not. When I want to do the get it returns null because it was never saved previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your code all seems correct, one suspicious part is maybe you call `getSetting` quickly after `saveSetting`. Can you try to put `getSetting` inside the callback of `saveSetting`? Which means `saveSetting` is async and you should make sure `saveSetting` is finished before you can `getSetting`.